# Rails & FriendlyID gem: how to redirect resource path to new friendly URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the [friendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) rails gem which is working great at generating a new friendly url slug. My issue is that users can still access the original resource path: `mydomain.com/movies/2`

How would I redirect the original resource path to the new friendly Url?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can redirect the old :id path to your friendly_id :slug path

```
# config/routes.rb
get "/movies/:id", to: "movies#redirect_to_slugged_url"
get "/movies/:slug", to: "movies#show", constraints: {slug: %r{\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/[^/]+}}, as: :movie


# app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def redirect_to_slugged_url
    movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to movie_path(movie)
  end

  def show
    @movie = Movie.friendly.find(params[:slug])
  end
end
```